# root role not getting reassigned to normal user (ex. tushar)

Tags: solaris

I want to reassign root role to user tushar,i had used :

```
usermod -R -root tushar 

usermod -R +root tushar .
```

The output:

```
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Permission denied. Cannot set roles, requires
solaris.role.delegate authorization.
UX: usermod: ERROR: Permission denied.
UX: usermod: ERROR: Cannot update system - login cannot be modified.
```

any help appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user needs the "User Security" profile to have the `solaris.role.deledate` authorization. As `root` issue:

```
usermod -P +"User Security" myuser
```

to add this profile. Then try again to add the root role to the other user with:

```
myuser@host:~$ pfexec usermod -R +root otheruser
```

If you have locked yourself out from becoming `root` you might be able to use `sudo` instead and issue:

```
sudo su -
usermod -R +root myuser
```

As last options you can reboot from a live CD, mount the root pool to a temporary location and edit the `/etc/user_attr` file to add:

```
myuser::::Profiles=System Administrator;roles=root;lock_after_retries=no
```

Comment: tushar@solaris:~$ usermod -P +"User Security" tushar   
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Permission denied. Cannot set profiles, requires solaris.profile.delegate authorization.
UX: usermod: ERROR: Permission denied.
UX: usermod: ERROR: Cannot update system - login cannot be modified.
tushar@solaris:~$

Comment: Did you issue the `usermod` command as `root`?

Comment: tushar@solaris:~$ pfexec usermod -R +root tushar
UX: usermod: ERROR: otheruser is not a valid user or role.
tushar@solaris:~$

Comment: you need to change `otheruser` to the username you want to modify...

Comment: no...i had used usermod -R -root tushar  ...as a normal user ....and now when i want to reassign the root role its not happening.....i had used otheruser to tushar

Comment: Did you try the `sudo` option?

Comment: hello Lambart...with "sudo" i can assume role of root now...also output of roles command is also giving root .Thanks for the help.....I would like to know why the normal command hasn't worked ..."usermod -R +root tushar" .......thanks again.:)

Comment: The reason is mentioned in the first line of the answer: You do not have the "User Security" profile. My question would be: How did the `usermod -R -root tushar` command succeed

Comment: yah...that i too need to find out.It succeded in the first attemt .,,,,root is the effective user in this case.